# jQuery: Changing the text of a button depending on the visibility state of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the text of a button when a table is visible or not by using **jQuery**. The problem is that jQuery `.is(":visible")` does not appear to do it. What am I doing wrong? I supposed that `.is(":visible")` is what is needed to check if an element is visible.

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#tabla" ).hide(); // We start hiding it.
    $("#boton").click(function() {

    var tabla = $("#tabla");

    tabla.fadeToggle();// Change the table visibility

    // An tell us if it is visible or not
    if (tabla.is(":visible")) {
        alert("It's visible"); // This is always called.
      // TODO Change button text.
    } else {
        alert("It isn't visible"); // This is never called.
      // TODO Change button text.
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><button id="boton">Show</button></p>
<table id="tabla" >
  <thead>
    <tr><th id="cabecera">First</th><th>Second</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td><td>Boo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) method will take a bit of time to execute and is executed in parallel [look for promises in jQuery]. In your code you are checking the visibility of the table as soon the fadeToggle is called, so it did not have time to complete yet.

Probably you want to check the visible after the function is completed. You would have to use a callback if you want to check when that toggle function is completed

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabla" ).hide(); // We start hiding it.
  $("#boton").click(function() {
    var tabla = $("#tabla");
    tabla.fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" , function(){
        // This function will be called when the fade function completes
        // An tell us if it is visible or not
        if (tabla.is(":visible")) {
          alert("It's visible");
          // TODO Change button text.
        } else {
          alert("It isn't visible");
          // TODO Change button text.
        }
    });   
  });
});
```

You can have a look on the logic behind deferred and promises in this [page](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/) or a [video](http://videos.bigbinary.com/jquery/jquery-deferred.html) that is explaining them.

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem exactly. Thanks that you have found the moved question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use to check the visibility :

```
if (tabla.css('display') != 'none') {
   alert('is visible');
} else {
   alert('is NOT visible');
}
```

Comment: Do you know why isn't my code ok? I want to use JQuery (if it can be used).

Comment: The code I put is jQuery. This is because .hide() adds a "display:none;" css directive to your table, so use my code to check and it'll be ok.

Comment: this question got answer! and it seems pretty good one for me! check the above answer!